# Elementary OS installation

Tags: system-installation

[image]

I am trying to install elementary OS in my windows 10 laptop but all I am seeing is that screen for about an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Which tutorial did you use to install Elementary OS in dual boot with Windows? Very important information is to describe step by step all actions you performed.